# How to configure ASP.NET Core 2 application with different url/port for different database

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, app-config

I'm trying to configure an ASP.NET Core (2.1) application in the same IIS server with two different url/port, each url/port should use different DataBase connection e.g.:

1. http://localhost:55001 (use QA DB connection)
2. http://localhost:55002 (use Production DB connection)

This scenario is for using an intranet web application. A group of users will use the Production app. Another group of users will use the QA or Staging app. **This two urls/db-connections must be enable in the same application at same time** in order to have one main app (for policies, maintaining and machine resources consumption purposes) and two different databases.

What I've tried is to configure two appsettings.json files: the first (appsettings.Release.json) sets the production database connection string and a applicationUrl url/port. The second one (appsettings.QA.json) defines a different database connection string and different applicationUrl.

appsettings.Release.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "default": {
      "ConnectionString": "<production-connection-string>",
      "ProviderName": "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
    }
  },
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:55001",
...
}
```

appsettings.QA.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "default": {
      "ConnectionString": "<qa-connection-string>",
      "ProviderName": "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
    }
  },
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:55002",
...
}
```

Now here I'm a little bit lost, the next configuration settings I need to achieve are confusing and not clear for me. I don't even know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible or acceptable.
If I define an ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable value for each appsettings[environment/scenario].json then I cannot use two values for this variable at the same time right?.

So I'm thinking that set and use the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT may not be the answear to my problem. Also I have to properly configure the startup and (maybe) program classes to achieve what I'm looking for.

So well at this point, any advice, guidance, code snippet or solution you guys may have will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question basically boils down to how to set different values for `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` per app instance. Pretty much your best bet there for an IIS deployment is adding an `<environmentVariables>` section in `<aspNetCore>` in your web.config:

```
<aspNetCore ...>
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Staging" />
    </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

To have that handled automatically for you when publishing, you'll need to modify the `.pubxml` for your publishing profile and add something like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EnvironmentName>Staging</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

That will then add the relevant `<environmentVariables>` setup to the generated web.config automatically when publishing.

For more information, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configuration-with-webconfig

Comment: Thanks Chris, I was able to configure the app with your mentioned solution, I can see that it uses the connection string depending on the environment. The only problem left, is that I cannot configure the custom url for each designed environments, I'm guessing I will be unable to do it because I'm hosting the app in IIS and that url config resides in IIS, or I haven't found the right documentation to acheive it.

Comment: Yeah. That part is unavoidable. The site bindings are in IIS.

Comment: I thought this would help me. The question was about different *appsettings.json* files. But I was surprised to find an answer about *web.config*. Have no idea how that happened. Wonder which *web.config* this even was.